# What is the name of this compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

This doesn't look like an amide. What is its IUPAC name? Is this compound even possible?
[image]

Comment: Without hydrogen at nitrogen, as you draw, uncharged – likely impossible.

Comment: Is it a homework? Just asking.

Comment: No .I asked it to one of my teachers, he said it is impossible to solve! I made up this question.

Comment: Just assume that hydrogen to be there.

Answer (score 5):

You likely mean $\ce{CH3-CO-NH-CO-CH2CH3}$.

$\ce{R-CO-NH-CO-R}$ compounds are called [imides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imide) (in contrast to *[amides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amide)* $\ce{R-CO-NH2}$, like in inorganic chemistry, $\ce{M^INH2}$ vs $\ce{M_{2}^{I}NH}$). They can also be „intramolecular“, i.e. cyclic (look at [succinimide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinimide) or [phthalimide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phthalimide)).

A similar symmetric compound $\ce{(CH3CO)2NH}$ „[diacetamide](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/12263)“ exists and can be bought (melting point 79 °C). Its current preferred name is *N*-acetylacetamide.

Your mixed imide of acetic and propionic acid is currently preferably named ***N*-acetylpropanamide**.

Comment: Just asking , what about something like (CH3CO)2N.

Comment: I mean (CH3CO)3N.

Comment: @compenthusiast Regarding the name, you should be able to solve it, the is analogous, and, according to the current IUPAC recommendations "asymmetric" as well (unfortunately, IMHO).

Comment: http://www.molbase.com/cas/641-06-5.html